# Okay to add a route to Node.js Express while listening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Obviously the typical example of adding routes to express follows something like the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Clearly, in most cases you know the `get` route exists before the server begins listening. But what if you want to dynamically create new routes once the server is listening? In other words, I want to do something like the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
  });
});
```

In practice the callback of the route would obviously be pulled dynamically from some remote source. I've tested the above code and everything appears to function properly, however, I was hoping to get confirmation that there wouldn't be any unintended side-effects of creating routes after app.listen is called before I move forward with this pattern.

Note: To clarify, I don't know what the routes will be when I write the main `server.js` file that will be creating the express server (hence why I can't create the routes before `listen` is called). The list of routes (and their respective handlers/callback functions) will be pulled from a database while the server is starting up/running.

Comment: Why do you need to wait until you begin listening to put that route together?

Comment: No real need to dynamically create the routes.  You could simply have all GET requests ('/*', function...  go to a single function that then parses the request.path and then send it to where ever you want from there.  That is a bit strange though, as websites generally have some form of structure to their directories.  At most you'd just need to use some regexp in the app.get('/someDir/:otherDir', function...  where :otherDir becomes a parameter (req.param('otherDir'))

Comment: it works, but it's not Ok!

Comment: @damphat why not? I generally call `listen` before I set up my routes.

Comment: @robertklep that is my feeling! database, middleware, routes are setup at initialization phase, we should wait for initialization done before listen(). If we call listen() before initialization is done, web-user may abuse this time to hack ..., oh just a feeling!

Comment: @damphat Node (or at least the interpreter) is single threaded; when you call `listen` it's merely queueing a listen request; if you set up middleware directly after it, it's all being executed within the same cycle of the event loop (granted, DB and other I/O is a bit different)

Comment: @robertklep yes, I know it is threadsafe, I just worry about the application logic.

Comment: To give a little background, this is being used for versioning a REST api that I'm creating. So basically, if a new version of a particular route is created I will be using what Chris suggested (creating a "route stub function" that will redirect to the appropriate version of that route). However, if a new route is added in a particular version of the api, then I would like to be able to add that route to the server without having to restart it.

Comment: So, just to clarify, I don't know what the routes will be when I write the main `server.js` file that will be creating the express server (hence why I can't create the routes before `listen` is called)

Comment: @Sanuden If you are making a REST API, and especially if you are going to be versioning it, take a look at [restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/). It’s designed to be similar to Express, but specifically for versioned REST APIs. Look at the documentation for “versioned routes”.

Comment: @Nate Yeah, I've actually used restify on a few other projects with great success. Unfortunately, this project requires (a) a hybrid server capable of serving traditional content more suited to express and (b) a very unique "versioning" concept not based on the `Accept-Version` header and consisting of some bizarre (though useful in our case) behavior. I did consider resify though, I just think in this case express is going to be the path of least resistance :-)

Comment: @Sanuden Ah, the real world. :-) Good luck.

Comment: Since there is a discussion here I thought I'd add why this question was relevant to me.


Part of my server's API depends on retrieving a set of external keys form a third party API. My express server starts listening to some routes, and simultaneously sends a request for keys to the other API. When it receives the keys, the additional routes are added.


I guess I could delay the call to `app.listen()` until the additional routes are added, but this seems correct to me.

Comment: @Sanuden a sample can be found here .. https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/expressjs-dynamic-runtime-routing/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[According to TJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/express-js/hwJ5-oMrt3M/OmRtbUxkTvcJ) (author of Express), it’s okay to add routes at runtime.

The main gotcha is going to be that routes are evaluated in the order they were added, so routes added at runtime will have a lower precedence than routes added earlier. This may or may not matter, depending on your API design.

Comment: you can reorder them by modifying the route stack