# Express can't use app.get

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create extra routes, however, whatever I try I always get "Cannot GET /x" error. What could be the reason?

Here's my server.js file;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// index page 
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});

app.get('/sample', function(req, res) {
    res.send('this is a sample!');  
});

// declaring static css
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 port');
```

My http://localhost:8080/sample gives me; "Cannot GET /sample"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the server solved the issue. This is interesting for me because [I thought we could add the routes on the run.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857865/okay-to-add-a-route-to-node-js-express-while-listening)